# как правильно заполнить таблицу данными из массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, for, таблицы

[image: получается так]

```
animals = [
    ['','mouse','Jerry'],
    ['','hamster','Biscuit'],
    ['','rabbit','Bugs'],
    ['','fox','Mrs. Fox'],
    ['','bear','Paddington']
];
animals = animals.flat();
console.log(animals)
food = [
    ['','apple',10],
    ['','pear',12],
    ['','tangerine',15],
    ['','lemon',5],
    ['','banana',7]
];

universes = [
    ['', 'DC', ['Superman', 'Batman', 'Wonder Woman']],
    ['❤️', 'Marvel', ['Iron Man', 'the Hulk', 'Black Widow']]
];


function getInfo (name){
        let trs = [];
    for (let tr = 1; tr <= 5; tr++){
        let tds = [];
            for ( let td = 1; td <= 3; td++){
             tds.push(`<td>${name[td-1]}</td>`)
             }
            trs.push(`<tr>${tds.join(` `)}</tr>`)
    
            }    
    
            document.write(`<table>

            ${trs.join(` `)}</table>`)
}

getInfo(animals);
// getInfo(food, undefined);
// getInfo(universes, undefined);
```

Код должен быть плюс минус такой , меня интересует что я не так делаю что бы таблица заполнялась .

[image: Должно быть так]

Comment: Вопрос-то в чём? Проблема-то в чём?

Comment: не могу сделать правильный цикл в функции для того что бы в таблицу подставлялись элементы массива как на картинке , максимум что у меня выходило это заполнить всю таблицу первым массивом animals . Вся таблица заполняется онфой о Джерри

Answer (score 2):

```js
animals = [
  ['', 'mouse', 'Jerry'],
  ['', 'hamster', 'Biscuit'],
  ['', 'rabbit', 'Bugs'],
  ['', 'fox', 'Mrs. Fox'],
  ['', 'bear', 'Paddington']
];

food = [
  ['', 'apple', 10],
  ['', 'pear', 12],
  ['', 'tangerine', 15],
  ['', 'lemon', 5],
  ['', 'banana', 7]
];

universes = [
  ['', 'DC', ['Superman', 'Batman', 'Wonder Woman']],
  ['❤️', 'Marvel', ['Iron Man', 'the Hulk', 'Black Widow']]
];


function getInfo(array, title) {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  table.innerHTML = `<caption>${title}</caption>`;
  table.innerHTML += array.map(e => 
    `<tr>${e.map(x => `<td>${x}</td>`).join``}</tr>`
  ).join``;
  return table;
}

document.body.appendChild(getInfo(food, 'Food info'));
document.body.appendChild(getInfo(animals, 'Animals info'));
document.body.appendChild(getInfo(universes, 'Universes info'));
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```